# Qt no matching function for call

Tags: c++, qt, nokia

I'm trying to connect a button click to a function, and pass an int value, but keep getting an error: no matching function for call to Main::connect...  I'm guessing that I'm not initializing something correct?

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {

    setupUI();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {

}

void MainWindow::setupUI() {

    QFrame* frame = new QFrame(this);

    _layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    frame->setLayout(_layout);

    parseXML();

    QScrollArea* scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    scrollArea->setWidget(frame);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

    setCentralWidget(scrollArea);
}

void MainWindow::parseXML() {

  this->parseItem(xml, count)

}

QMap<QString, QString> MainWindow::parseItem(QXmlStreamReader& xml, int count) {

    QString valueName = "buttonid";

    QSignalMapper *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(valueName);
    _layout->addWidget(button);
    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(addMenu(int)));
    signalMapper->setMapping(button, valueName);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked())), signalMapper, SIGNAL(map());

    return something;
}


void MainWindow::addMenu(int count) {

    _layoutToAdd = new QVBoxLayout;

    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("New Button");
    _layoutToAdd->addWidget(button);

    _layout->insertLayout(count, _layoutToAdd, 0);

}
```

mainwindow.h

```
ublic:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void parseXML();
    void addMenu(int count);

signals:
    void clicked();
```

Comment: Giving the complete error message would help.

Answer (score 3):

There's a syntax error in your code. Count your parenthesis :

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked())), signalMapper, SIGNAL(map());
//     ^              ^       ^^^^
//     1              2       3321 <-- All your parenthesis are closed at this point
// meaning you are calling connect() with only 2 parameters
```

Comment: There is also one missing, after SIGNAL(map())

Answer (score 1):

You must white  Q_OBJECT (for using signals and slots ) in descriction of your class

```
class MainWindow: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
```